# Canvas Game, How to keep it refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So i made this game of Pong for Canvas for a project of mine but i cant seem to make it continue after the first frame. Can someone help me make this game continue to work after its first frame?
HTML First Then JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Connor's COMP-106 Pong</title>

    <script src="js/CCAdventure-Example.js"></script>
</head>
<canvas id="gc" width="640" Height="480"></canvas>
```

```
p1y=p2y=40;
        pt=10;
        ph=100;
        bx=by=50;
        bd=6;
        xv=yv=4;
        score1=score2=0;
        ais=2;
        window.onload=function(){
            c=document.getElementById('gc');
            cc=c.getContext('2d');
            setInterval(update,1000/30);

        }
    function reset(){
        bx=c.width/2;
        by=c.height/2;
        xv=-xv;
        yv=3;
    }
    function update(){
        bx+=xv;
        by+=yv;
        if(by<0 && yv<0){
            yv=-yv;
        }
        if(by>c.height && yv>0){
            yv=-yv;
        }
        if(bx<0){
            if(by>p1y && by<p1y+ph){
                xv=-xv;
                dy=by-(p1y+ph/2);
                yv = dy*0.3;
            } else{
                score2++;
                reset();
            }
        }
        if(bx>c.width){
            if(by>p2y && by<p2y+ph){
                xv=-xv;
                dy=by-(p2y+ph/2);
                yv = dy*0.3;
            } else{
                score1++;
                reset();
            }
        }
        if(p2y+ph/2<by){
            p2y+=ais;
        } else{
            p2y-=ais;
        }


        cc.fillstyle='black';
        cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
        cc.fillStyle='white';
        cc.fillRect(0,p1y,pt,ph);
        cc.fillRect(c.width-pt,p2y,pt,ph);
        cc.fillRect(bx-bd/2,by-bd/2,bd,bd);
        cc.fillText(score1,100,100);
        cc.fillText(score2,c.width-100,100);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add logging to your code inside `reset` or `update` you can see the code is still drawing (and winning).

The reason you're not seeing any update is you have a typo of `cc.fillstyle='black';` instead of `cc.fillStyle='black';` which is preventing you from seeing your "white" paddle, ball, and score.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcdg0pjL/)

(I changed a couple of variable names to keep track of what was going on)

PS. Im not sure performance wise if it makes much of a difference, but i like to use `.clearRect()` before drawing my shapes again so that i know im working with an empty canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Your set interval was ok, but every each iteration you create black cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height) which was coveres previous white drawings. You should move cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height) before setInterval and draw it just once.

```js
var c,cc;
p1y=p2y=40;
        pt=10;
        ph=100;
        bx=by=50;
        bd=6;
        xv=yv=4;
        score1=score2=0;
        ais=2;
        window.onload=function(){
            c=document.getElementById('gc');
            cc=c.getContext('2d');
   cc.fillstyle='black';
   cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
            setInterval(update,1000/30);

        };
    function reset(){
        bx=c.width/2;
        by=c.height/2;
        xv=-xv;
        yv=3;
    }
    function update(){
        bx+=xv;
        by+=yv;
        if(by<0 && yv<0){
            yv=-yv;
        }
        if(by>c.height && yv>0){
            yv=-yv;
        }
        if(bx<0){
            if(by>p1y && by<p1y+ph){
                xv=-xv;
                dy=by-(p1y+ph/2);
                yv = dy*0.3;
            } else{
                score2++;
                reset();
            }
        }
        if(bx>c.width){
            if(by>p2y && by<p2y+ph){
                xv=-xv;
                dy=by-(p2y+ph/2);
                yv = dy*0.3;
            } else{
                score1++;
                reset();
            }
        }
        if(p2y+ph/2<by){
            p2y+=ais;
        } else{
            p2y-=ais;
        }



        cc.fillStyle='white';
        cc.fillRect(0,p1y,pt,ph);
        cc.fillRect(c.width-pt,p2y,pt,ph);
        cc.fillRect(bx-bd/2,by-bd/2,bd,bd);
        cc.fillText(score1,100,100);
        cc.fillText(score2,c.width-100,100);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="640" Height="480"></canvas>
```